# Why Roslyn is generating method code without spaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

What am I doing wrong that Roslyn is generating code without any space between identifiers and keywords? It is also putting a semicolon at the end of the method block. 
Here is my code:

```
SeparatedSyntaxList<ParameterSyntax> parametersList = new SeparatedSyntaxList<ParameterSyntax>().AddRange
(new ParameterSyntax[]
    {
        SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("sender")).WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("object")),
        SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("args")).WithType(SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("EventArgs"))
    }
);

MethodDeclarationSyntax newMethod = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
    SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword)),
    SyntaxFactory.ParseName("void"),
    null,
    SyntaxFactory.Identifier("simpleButton1_Click"),
    null,
    SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(parametersList),
    SyntaxFactory.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
    SyntaxFactory.Block(),
    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)
);
```

And here is the result that I am having:

```
privatevoidsimpleButton1_Click(objectsender,EventArgse){};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's putting the semicolon there because you are passing one to the method that creates the method declaration, I'm guessing this is used when declaring an abstract method without a body.

To correctly format the output you could use the `Formatter` class in the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting` namespace.

```
Workspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
SyntaxNode formattedNode = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting.Formatter.Format(newMethod, workspace);
```

For the return type you could do the following

```
SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword));
```

This will give you a `TypeSyntax`

Answer (score 13):

To be even more comprehensive, [`NormalizeWhiteSpace`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNodeExtensions.cs,4e9be506a84af634) should be mentioned. It applies default formatting to the given node:

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax newMethod = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
    SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword)),
    SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.VoidKeyword)),
    null,
    SyntaxFactory.Identifier("simpleButton1_Click"),
    null,
    SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(parametersList),
    SyntaxFactory.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
    SyntaxFactory.Block(),
    null
  )

newMethod = newMethod.NormalizeWhitespace();
```

A `ToString()` on that will produce the expected output:

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}
```

Comment: NormalizeWhitespace works for me. It adds spaces (lots of them) but at least ensures a space between keywords and ids

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs,f445ffe3c814c002) to format the syntax nodes that you generate.

Comment: Thanks @Tamas for the suggestion but it doesn't appear to work. What I got from this method is, it will add additional annotations on the method that I am not looking to insert. Instead I just want to create correct method syntax.

Comment: Where are you generating this code? Is this in a codefix provider and are you inside Visual Studio? If not, you'll need to use `Formatter.Format()` on  the syntax node that you want to format.

Comment: Formatter.Format fixes parameters part but still the method declaration is like "privatevoidButton1_Click". 

Probably defined modifier by  `SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword))` and returnType by `SyntaxFactory.ParseName("void")` is not the best way to go. Any idea how to improve it? 

BTW an ugly hack is to parse `" void "` instead of `"void"` to find desired results

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me in a roslyn CodeFixProvider I'm working on.

I found on reliable solution was to change the method type name to `" void "` (Note the spaces).

It fixed it from `privatevoidMethod() {` to `private void Method() {`

```
MethodDeclarationSyntax method = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
            SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
            SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword)),
            SyntaxFactory.ParseName(" void "), // <--------------!!!!
            null,
            SyntaxFactory.Identifier("Method"),
            null,
            SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(),
            SyntaxFactory.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
            SyntaxFactory.Block(SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(bodyText)),
            null)
            .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);
        return method;
```

Then, I added the method to the classDeclarationSyntax, updated the root node with the new ClassDeclarationSyntax, and called:

```
await Formatter.FormatAsync(document)
```

This last bit made the correct indentation in the class etc.

For me using `NormalizeWhiteSpace();` added 2 spaces instead of 1, even after calling format.